# Array object dictionary accessing whole array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, search, dictionary

I'm trying to access every name in the beers array for a search algorithm. I have the array set up as a dictionary,but it doesn't behave quite like a dictionary. Here is what the data looks like:[image]

Just so you can see how I've been accessing the array, here is how I populated my uitableview.So, basically I know how to access individual objects in the arrray but I can't access the whole array. :

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text=[self.beers[indexPath.row] name]
```

Then again I might be totally off base. I'm still learning objective c and ios here so sorry if my inexperience shows through in my post. any tips help. Thanks guys!

Comment: Is it correct to assume that `Beer` is a custom class, with a `NSString` property called `name`?

Comment: @user3386109 yes that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want a new array that contains just the names of each `Beer` object and not the object itself. You can use an array "mapping" function like in this category.

```
typedef id(^MapBlock)(id input);

@implementation NSArray (Additions)
- (NSArray *)arrayByMappingWithBlock:(MapBlock)block {
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:self.count];
    for (id obj in self) {
        [array addObject:block(obj)];
    }
    return array;
}
@end
```

You would then use it like so...

```
NSArray *beerNames = [self.beers arrayByMappingWithBlock:^id(Beer *beer) {
    return beer.name;
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure if that is what you want to achieve, but the following line will produce an array containing all beer names:

```
[self.beers valueForKeyPath:@"name"];
```

Comment: It's getting to the point where you guys are just doing my code for me, but for the record I got this runtime error when I implemented using that:valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.

Comment: Then either "name" is not a property of the Beer class or there is another object in your beers array that is not an instance of the Beer class.

Answer (score 0):

You can access all of the names in the array by iterating through the array with a loop

```
for ( Beer *beer in self.beers )
    NSLog( @"%@", beer.name );
```